Continuous function with a countably infinite number of poles are not improperly Riemann integrable.
How to show that $$f=\frac{1}{\prod_{n=1}^\infty(x-\frac{1}{n})}$$
is not (improperly) Riemann integrable?
Motivation. It is bookwork to show that bounded functions with a finite number of discontinuities are Riemann integrable. The result can be extended to include functions with poles of finite order. Yet, it is counter intuitive to me that this result cannot be extended to functions with a countably infinite number discontinuities, nor a general discrete set of discontinuities.
And so to seek a counter example, I wrote down this function as a Lebesgue integrable function with a countably infinite non-discrete set of discontinuity, and want to show that it is not improperly Riemann integrable.

The product $\prod_n (x-\frac1n)$ diverges, so your function is only going to assume the values $0$ and $\infty$. To fix that you may want to work with $\tilde f(x):=\prod (x-\frac1{n^2})$
